# How to find time of last reboot android?

Tags: android, service, binding

I am attempting to find time of the last android reboot using service and broadcastreceiver. My "Broadcast" class should record the time immediately after the restart. In the "OnCreate" method a calculated time, but it does not work.

What am I doing wrong?

My "Server" class:

```
public class Server extends Service{

IBinder mBinder = new LocalBinder();

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return mBinder;
}

public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
    public Server getServerInstance() {
        return Server.this;
    }
} }
```

My "Client" class:

```
public class Client extends Activity {

boolean mBounded;
Server mServer;
TextView text;
Button button;
Broadcast bc = new Broadcast();

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    text = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

    Intent mIntent = new Intent(this, Server.class);
    bindService(mIntent, mConnection, BIND_AUTO_CREATE);

    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            text.setText(String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis() - bc.t));
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    Intent mIntent = new Intent(this, Server.class);
    bindService(mIntent, mConnection, BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
}

ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {

    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
        Toast.makeText(Client.this, "Service is disconnected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        mBounded = false;
        mServer = null;
    }

    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
        Toast.makeText(Client.this, "Service is connected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        mBounded = true;
        LocalBinder mLocalBinder = (LocalBinder)service;
        mServer = mLocalBinder.getServerInstance();
    }
};

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    if(mBounded) {
        unbindService(mConnection);
        mBounded = false;
    }
}}
```

"Broadcast" class:

```
public class Broadcast extends BroadcastReceiver {
public long t;
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    t = System.currentTimeMillis();
    Intent serviceLauncher = new Intent(context, Server.class);
    context.startService(serviceLauncher);
}}
```

Manifest:

```
<receiver android:name="com.example.serv.Broadcast" android:enabled="true" android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <service android:enabled="true" android:name=".Server"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

> What am I doing wrong?

Probably, not reading the [docs](https://developer.android.com) enough?

There is a readily available API, [`SystemClock.uptimeMillis()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/SystemClock.html#uptimeMillis%28%29) which

> Returns milliseconds since boot, *not counting time spent in deep sleep*.

You may also use [`SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/SystemClock.html#elapsedRealtime%28%29) which

> Returns milliseconds since boot, *including time spent in sleep*.

Comment: task to start counting time after rebooting. Do not use system functions

Comment: Ah, you should have mentioned that this is a homework.